# CakePHP - Authenticating with MD5

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, md5

I'm working on a CakePHP application that needs to connect to a remote database for authentication. Passwords are stored with MD5 encryption, when I was coding the app, I used sha encryption for my localhost database, now the app doesn't allow me to login to since the schema are different. How can I force cakePHP to authenticate users using MD5?

Comment: Does it absolutely needs to be in MD5? It is considered cryptographically broken http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: You might as well use plain text.

Comment: I know MD5 is not recommended at all, but the old system was implemented 2 years ago... For now I need to cope with it till I change everything from MD5 hashing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585573/1794539)

I do not recommend the use of this code in any scenario, ever. MD5 is a horrible hashing algorithm for security as it is too resource-light to discourage cracking. It also has known vulnerabilities. Use bcrypt or SHA-512.

To do this, you can edit `AppController.php` like this:

```
<?php
// AppController.php

public function beforeFilter()
{
    Security::setHash('md5');
}
?>
```

However, this is **not recommended as MD5 is a very poor password hashing algorithm**. You're far better adding a function to allow users to login with existing `md5` passwords, encouraging them to upgrade to the new hash, and not allowing any new users to set MD5 passwords.

If, instead you want to use a secure function like `bcrypt`, you can do the following:

```
<?php
// AppController.php

public function beforeFilter()
{
    Security::setHash('blowfish');
}
?>
```

When comparing plaintext values to hashes, you have to pass the original hash as the salt value in order to retain cost parameters etc:

```
$newHash = Security::hash($newPassword, 'blowfish', $storedPassword);
```